# Setting Authorization Header with token is not working

Tags: swift, authentication, authorization

I recently faced issue where the bearer token set in the http header field of URLRequest is not getting set randomly and receiving invalid token from backend. When I deep dived I understood Apple  discourages setting Authorization token manually.

I saw some other posts who are asking to use Authentication challenge where I see use of URLCredentials which has user name and password from UI. But catch here in next app launch I don't have user password even in RAM as its not stored and can be severe security issue. So we store encrypted token locally to carry out the session. Can any one help me how to get this done without using the user credentials.

Thanks,